# Text validation on multiple elements with the same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple input elements in multiple forms that have the same id in the same page. Each form has the same actions (create, update, and delete) for adding new team names, modifying team names, or deleting team names. I was trying to come up with a simple text validation technique to display a message if the textbox in that particular form is empty. I came up with this, which works for the first element in the first form in the page.

```
    function showProgressOfNameChange(){
    var newName = document.getElementById("newName").value;
     if (newName == null || newName == "") {
       document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Name must not be empty";
       document.getElementById("newName").style.backgroundColor = "#ff8";
       return false;
       }
     $("#loading-div-background").show();
 }
```

But this won't work on other elements with the id=newName in the same page. Perhaps I should use getElementsByClass, but not sure how to get that to work... 
If I change all the ids to be unique how do I write the function to check multiple unique ids?

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique**

Comment: So if I change all the ids to be unique how do I write the function to check multiple unique ids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have suggested, you need to use class instead of ID, as ID has to be unique, then you can use [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) to get all elements with the said class then you iterate over the list of elements returned and do the validation for each items

```
function showProgressOfNameChange() {
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("newName"),
        newName;
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        newName = els[i].value;
        if (newName == null || newName == "") {
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Name must not be empty";
            els[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ff8";
            return false;
        }
    }
    $("#loading-div-background").show();
    return true;
}
```

---

Since you tagged it with jQuery

```
function showProgressOfNameChange() {
    var valid = true;
    $('.newName').each(function () {
        if (this.value == null || this.value == "") {
            valid = false;
            $(this).css('background-color', '#ff8');
        }
    })
    $("#loading-div-background").toggle(valid);
    $("#error").toggle(!valid)
    if (!valid) {
        $("#error").html("Name must not be empty");
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kL1ar4vx/)